# how can a write a test case for this void method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I want to write a junit test case for this method

```
public class LinkModel {

    @Inject
    @Optional
    private String path;

    private static final String CONTENTPATH="/content";

    private String link;


    @PostConstruct
    protected void init(){
        link=path;
        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(path) && isInternal()){
            link=path+ "";
        }
  private boolean isInternal(){
        return path.contains(CONTENTPATH);
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }
    }
```

I know void methods are usually not tested but this has some extra logic that should be tested.

Comment: Calling that method does not seem to have any side effects. It sets a variable, but that variable is not used. What is the *visible behavior* that you need to test?

Comment: @Joni modified the question

Comment: The init methods seems to miss a closing bracket. Can you fix the formatting? Also: if you explain in words in the question what the class is supposed to do, this can guide the design of test cases for this class.

Answer (score 0):

> I know void methods are usually not tested

That's... not true.

Make a getter for that `link` field. You may make it package private (no access modifier at all) if you want, or even document it with `@ForTesting`.  Now you can test that your method modifies link as desired (and if this is your real code, the test will fail; you don't change path at all; adding an empty string to a string like this doesn't change it. Unless `path` is null, in which case, this replaces the null pointer with a pointer to the string `"null"`. Which.. seems weird.

NB: Don't use StringUtils. It's bad.

For example, `StringUtils.isNotBlank` has a ton of problems:

1. 'not' in method names is bad; !StringUtils.isBlank() would be more readable.
2. It is wrong; it will answer 'false' if you pass in null, and that is incorrect. null is not some sort of alternative take on the notion of an empty string. `null` means something along the lines of 'no value' or 'unknown'. If I ask you: "I have an unknown shirt. Is it red?", then the only sensible answer would be: "Um? I don't know!". Neither "Yes, it is red" nor "No, it is not" is correct.
3. Java already has this! Just call `path.isBlank()`. Or rather, `!path.isBlank()`.

Answer (score 0):

void methods can be tested

1. If they having any object as parameter, after a method call those parameters can be asserted
2. If the methods throwing any exceptions, we can assert whether the method throwing exceptions or not

Demo Class

```
public class Demo
```

{

```
private String path="dummy";

private static final String CONTENTPATH="/content";

private String link;


protected void init()
{
    if(path.length()>0)
    {
        link=path+ "";
    }
}

private boolean isInternal()
{
    return path.contains(CONTENTPATH);
}

public String getLink() 
{
    return link;
}
```

}

Test Case

```
class DemoTest {

    @Test
    void test() {
        Demo obj = new Demo();
        obj.init();
        assertEquals("dummy", obj.getLink());
    }

}
```

Comment: how the condition StringUtils.isNotBlank(path) &&  isInternal() ... should'nt that be tested

Comment: if we have setter for field "path" then we can set empty for one case and non empty for another case and then we can perform assertion